# Знаки зодиака: с какой буквы?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я — Телец, а она — Стрелец.

> Я — телец, а она — стрелец.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ вам дан уже в другом вопросе. Не следовало создавать дубликата. Кроме того, не зазорно обратится к поисковику с такими простыми вещами.
Согласно астрологической традиции, названия планет, знаков Зодиака и Восточного гороскопа пишутся с прописной (большой) буквы.

Comment: Надо разве писать *знаки Зодиака*, а не *знаки зодиака*?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы вкладываете в это слово. Чаще всего правильнее писать со строчной (маленькой), так как "зодиак" это название разных астрологических моделей. Но в астрологической литературе, как правило, подразумевают один конкретный зодиак, западный. Когда говорим о чём-то конкретном, то можно писать с прописной (большой). Это уже как имя собственное: солнце и Солнце. Лично я пишу "Зодиак" с большой буквы в силу того, что мне чаще приходится употреблять именно в общении с теми людьми, которые всегда его пишут с прописной. Но лучше писать со сточной, так вы не ошибётесь.

Comment: Ну, тут не может быть никаких вопросов. Плюсую ответ.